# Ruby claims " " isn't actually a space?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to troubleshoot why Ruby isn't splitting my string by empty spaces. For example:

```
[1] pry(#<irb>)> msg
=> "!iex <http://test-domain.com.au|test-domain.com.au> <mailto:first.last@test-domain.com.au|first.last@test-domain.com.au> FirstName"
[2] pry(#<irb>)> msg.split(" ")
=> ["!iex <http://test-domain.com.au|test-domain.com.au> <mailto:first.last@test-domain.com.au|first.last@test-domain.com.au> FirstName"]
[3] pry(#<irb>)> msg.include? " "
=> false
[8] pry(#<irb>)> msg.inspect
=> "\"!iex <http://test-domain.com.au|test-domain.com.au> <mailto:first.last@test-domain.com.au|first.last@test-domain.com.au> FirstName\""
[9] pry(#<irb>)>
```

As you can see above, my string appears to contain spaces, but the `split` method isn't working on it. I tried to run `inspect` on the string just to see if something else was being displayed, but it doesn't really make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the string contains [some other kind of whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) or you're splitting on some other kind of whitespace. For example `"foo\u2002bar"` will look like `foo bar` but contains a special space.

Try [`msg.dump`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-dump) to see the special characters.

```
2.6.5 :008 > msg = "foo\u2002bar"
 => "foo bar" 
2.6.5 :009 > msg.dump
 => "\"foo\\u2002bar\""
```

To split on any space or tab, split on the `[[:blank:]]` [character class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes).

```
2.6.5 :006 > msg.split(/[[:blank:]]/)
 => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thanks. `msg.dump` actually showed `\u0040` as what was being displayed as whitespace/blank. This solution worked for me.

Comment: @LewlSauce `\u0040` is @. Are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, typo. That was actually `\u00A0`

Comment: @LewlSauce Non-breaking space. Glad it's all working.